# ionic 3 html button linked to a funtion in .ts but says its undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3

I have this line of code which I have at the end of a sign-up type form:

```
<button ion-button full color="secondary" onclick="save()"></button>`
```

However when I click on it I get an error saying save is undefined but I have this in my .ts file

```
save() {
  this.submitAttempt= true;
  console.log("success!");
  console.log(this.slideOneForm.value);
  console.log(this.slideTwoForm.value);
  console.log(this.slideThreeForm.value);
}
```

Is my mistake in the definition or in the button itself and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide us more of your code so that we can debug? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sonicd300 already answered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in the button's html, you bind it like `(click)="save()"` not `onclick="save()"`

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of the Ionic live reloader (debug server). So you have 2 options here.

*Option 1:* Change something on `.ts` file and allow to server reload again

*Option 2:* Kill the server and restart it again using `ionic serve`